# How to force a user in ASP.NET Core to agree on the terms and conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a project that is written using C# on the top of ASP.NET Core 6 framework.

I have a rule that no signed in user can use the app unless he/she signs some documents. These agreements are in the database.

So after the user logs in, I check to see if there are any required agreements that need to be signed. If any is needs signature and the user have not sign them, I add a claim to the user (i.e, `MustSign` claim type).

Now I need a way on every request to check if there is an authorized user, check the claims for `MustSign` claim. If the user has this claim then I was to redirect the user to a controller/action where he/she must sign the agreement before continuing. These rules cannot be applied on the page that allows anonymous access like error page, logout, privacy, home page...

How can I intercept the incoming request and evaluate the claims and redirect "when needed"?

Comment: `.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().Require[......].Build();` (see https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/ for an example). Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320155/asp-net-core-3-0-policy-redirect